# I can't get all the div's to show up with the same #id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/bDQt7/4/

This doesn't work, hello2 and hello3 won't show up. It has to do with the '#id can only be used once' ? Changing it to class doesn't work, how to fix this?

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:unhide('menu');">Toggle</a>

<div id="menu" class="hidden">hello</div>
<div id="menu" class="hidden">hello2</div>
<div id="menu" class="hidden">hello3</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.unhidden {
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
        item.className = (item.className == 'hidden') ? 'unhidden' : 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Yes, but how to change it so it will work? I changed the getElementById to ByClass and still not working

Comment: You want to use classes, which can be duplicated on the page. Id's need to be unique on a page or you get screwy behavior and you DOM won't behave right. certain browsers will handle it different ways, but it will certainly not be good!

Comment: There is no getElementByClass, you may need to use jQuery to help you easily do the selection.

Comment: Yes, but how to change it so it will work? I changed the getElementById to ByClass and still not working

Comment: jQuery is a helpful library to load and help you to use javascript to easily let you accomplish task in a cross browser fashion: http://jquery.com/

Comment: [`getElementsByClass`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), not `Element`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs must be unique.

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="hidden">hello</div>
<div class="hidden">hello2</div>
<div class="hidden">hello3</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){    
        $("div").toggleClass("hidden unhidden");
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bDQt7/5/)

Comment: That's not JS! It's jQuery, the guy doesn't know what jQuery is, that's not a reasonable answer...you can't include a library without even telling him or loading it!

Comment: I saw tag jQuery so answered this way

Comment: I agree that is the way he should do it, but you need to edit your answer to include loading jQuery.

Comment: That doesn't load jQuery...but is part of the way and certainly needed for a beginner to use the code, he needs to load the actual jquery library from a cdn or something or locally.

Comment: Anyway, I've added <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script> to load jQuery. I hate to download jQuery and put it into my own files. Your code works with it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Jquery solution for you, I just replaced your id with another unique class. Just refer the code below to get a grip over it.

### HTML

```
<a href="#">Toggle</a>

<div  class="xTest hidden">hello</div>
<div  class="xTest hidden">hello2</div>
<div  class="xTest hidden">hello3</div>
```

### JQUERY

```
$("a").click(function(){

    var xObj = $(".xTest");

    if(xObj.hasClass("hidden"))
    {
        xObj.removeClass("hidden").addClass("unhidden");
    }
    else
    {
        xObj.removeClass("unhidden").addClass("hidden");
    }

});
```

### [DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/bDQt7/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't your wrap all your divs inside another div?

http://jsfiddle.net/bDQt7/7/

it has more sense to have menu and items inside it (I guess you need anchors and not divs inside the menu div)

That way you don't need jquery if you still don't know what it is.

```
<div id='menu' class='hidden'>
  <a href='#'>menu</a>
  <a href='#'>menu2</a>
  <a href='#'>menu3</a>
</div>
```